# Hide the ETA screen in Waze when starting a new navigation

Tags: waze

When starting new navigation in Waze, I want to drive right away: I don't want to have to click on Go or wait ~ 13 seconds to remove this screen:

[image]

<sup>(Click the image to see its larger variant)</sup>

Is there any way to automatically bypass / hide / remove that ETA screen?